# Video Poker - RTP

Tags: poker

[This site](http://wizardofodds.com/games/video-poker/strategy/jacks-or-better/9-6/simple/) shows that using a 'simple' strategy or an 'optimal' strategy in Jacks Or Better 'fullpay' pay table(see below) video poker results in $99\%$ return-to-player (RTP). RTP is defined as the fraction of money won to money wagered.

What would the RTP be in each of these 2 'dumb' strategies:

1. Player replaces all cards every time.
2. Whenever the player has any win in the initial draw, he replaces all cards which are not part of the win. For example if the user sees AA33J he will hold AA and replace 33J.

Thanks!

Pay table

- Royal flush  800
- Straight flush   50
- Four of a kind   25
- Full house   9
- Flush    6
- Straight 4
- Three of a kind  3
- Two pair 2
- Pair 1

Comment: I added an explanation for RTP (don't think many people here knows this abbreviation). See if it makes sense. btw there is a [Poker SE site](http://poker.stackexchange.com/) that might be better suited for this question.

Comment: You need to specify the payoffs. Not only do we try to make questions on this site self-contained (i.e. not reliant on links, which might go dead), but it also seems that there are different conventions -- in fact the very page you linked to specifies a different payoff for a royal flush than [the one it links to](http://wizardofodds.com/games/video-poker/tables/jacks-or-better/). To make the question well-defined you should include a table of payoffs, and also explain how the game works (I gather that one is allowed to discard an arbitrary number of cards once).

Comment: Added the pay table